# How to edit web.xml in Grails?

Tags: grails, web.xml

When you do a `grails create-app`, it doesn't look like a `web.xml` gets generated anywhere. According to the latest docs, it sounds like running `grails install-templates` will place `web.xml` to your `src/templates/war` directory. A few questions about this:

- We are currently on Grails 2.4.4: is this still the modern/recommended way of accessing your `web.xml` and making modifications to it?
- Can someone confirm that modifying this generated `web.xml` (e.g. adding a servlet filter) will actually override and take affect when the app runs?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes, that's still the accepted method for modifying `web.xml` in Grails 2.4.x and yes, the changes you make there will be reflected in the deployed application.